# How to output the results of several commands in one line?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have this bash command line:

```
{echo -n ROT: \  ; date ; tree /Volumes/WD\ Ultra\ 2TB\ ROT/Bilder\ Archiv | tail -1 ;} >> /Users/reinard/Desktop/TestRot.txt
```

I expected to have this output:

```
ROT:  Sa  5 Dez 2015 18:14:52 EET 6651 directories, 208455 files
```

but I get always this (2 lines):

```
ROT:  Sa  5 Dez 2015 18:14:52 EET
6651 directories, 208455 files
```

I tried and read a lot. No success... :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is `date` program which printed newline after date.

Try replacing `date` with

```
echo -n `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date | tr -d '\n'` instead of `date`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a newline character replacement via powershell on your date and tree outputs.

https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [edit] and explain (give an example) *here* how to do this. Link-only answers are low quality. The link should stay as a reference, but the answer should be standalone. Also note the question is about Bash. You want to include PowerShell so please explain how to make the two work together in this particular case. Will the result be available back in Bash?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

```
echo -n 'ROT:      ' $(date) ' :: ' $(tree /Volumes/WD\ Ultra\ 2TB\ ROT/Bilder\ Archiv | tail -1) $'\n' >> /Users/reinard/Desktop/ArchivBilderCount.txt
```

Comment: Can you add a sentence or two to identify the problem and explain how this fixes it?  That will make it a lot more useful to others with a similar problem.  Thanks.